# Sitecore CDP Dashboard Report

Tags: cdp

I am exploring the Sitecore CDP dashboard. In the Summary Report it is showing number of reports like Guest Type, New Visitors, Converted, Abandoned etc. reports. I want to further drill down the report to see the user details. However I could not find a way to get the details of users. Even if downloading the reports don't contains user info.
Please let me how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the prebuilt dashboards have very specific usecases that they are showing data for.  There are a few dashboards that allow you to pull the CSV of the data, however most do not provide access to the raw data including the specific guests that matched in that report.

Sounds like however, you are looking for more of the raw data that you can get inside an S3 bucket of your Sitecore CDP Data Lake.  This is not provided out of the box, however you can reach out to Sitecore support to provide this raw data to you, so that you can create your own dashboards (using Power BI, Tableau or any Business Intelligence software) for your organization, or use this data to explore specific trends.  This data is provided to you on a daily basis and you can move to your own S3 buckets or do with that data as you wish.

[image]

You can learn more about the Data Lake export service here in the Sitecore Documentation: <strike>https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-0/using-sitecore-cdp-data-lake-export-service.html</strike>

New link: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/api/data-lake-export-service.html

Answer (score -1):

Enabling Developer mode gives you all the details about a specific session
To enable it you`d check [this](https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-cdp/enable-feature-flags-in-sitecore-cdp.html) and [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-cdp/use-debug-mode-in-sitecore-cdp.html) details about how to use it.

From those docs:

### Enable feature flags in Sitecore CDP

> To enable a feature flag:
>
> 1. In the navigation pane, hover the mouse over the Sitecore CDP tenant
>    name, then hover over your name, as shown in the following image.
> 2. Click **Feature Flags**.
>
> ***Note:** The features that you can enable depend on your role. Most user
> roles only have access to the debug feature.*
>
> 3. To enable a feature, in the **Features** list, in the **Enabled** column, turn
>    on the switch. If you do not immediately have access to
>    the feature, try logging out and logging back into Sitecore CDP.

### Use debug mode in Sitecore CDP

> If you enable the debug feature flag, you can view data in a table or
> JSON format on certain screens. This is useful when troubleshooting
> experiments, because you can access all the data in a guest profile
> either in a table or in JSON format.
>
> To use debug mode:
>
> 1. Click the Debug icon next to the data you want to access.
>    There are multiple screens within the Sitecore CDP application that
>    this icon displays on.
>
> The following image shows the debug feature that is available on the
> guest profile page.
> [image: Accessing the debug feature in the guest profile.]
>
> 2. Depending on where you clicked the icon, a window displays that includes data in a table.
>
> The following image shows the window that displays if you click the
> Debug icon on the guest profile screen.
> [image: Viewing debug mode in a table format.]
>
> 3. To see the data in JSON format, click Show as JSON. A JSON representation of data displays, as shown in the following image.
>    [image: Viewing debug mode in JSON format.]
> 4. To download the JSON to a local
>    destination, click the gray gear icon, then **Download**. Alternatively, to
>    copy the JSON to the clipboard, click **Copy**.
> 5. To return to the previous screen, click the close icon.

Comment: Please add a description here as well from the link as the link may expire in the future.